# GeckoDriver issue

Tags: python, macos, selenium, geckodriver

I have updated my macOS to Version 10.15 (Catalina) and after running webdriver I get this warning message.

Could someone please assist?

[gechodriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEfmM.png)

Comment: Hello, please introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question.

Answer (score 2):

Catalina requires all apps that are signed with developer IDs to be 'notarized' by Apple. In the absence of an updated version from the developer, you can try the following:

Right-click and select "Open". This may bring up the same dialog, but with an option to Open the file anyway.

You can get around this by removing the quarantine Extended Attribute on the file:

xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/file

Naturally, this bypasses Apple's security precautions which exist to stop maliciously altered software from running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this did not solve my problem.

Comment: The first solution proposed here:
"Right-click and select "Open". This may bring up the same dialog, but with an option to Open the file anyway."
-- Solved it for me. It only needs to be done once and it releases the file from the quarantine situation.
As for the second suggestion (proposed also on the official gecko driver documentation) - that didn't work for me: it locked the file in some strange state where is immediately existed when launched (might be a 3rd party issue, though)